# Iterated conditioning

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability

I understand how this holds:

$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|\mathit{G})|\mathit{H}) = \mathbb{E}(X|\mathit{H})$

where $\mathit{H} \subset \mathit{G} $.

Then, how does this hold:

$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|\mathit{G})) = \mathbb{E}(X)$

as here, $\mathit{H} = \Omega$ and now $\mathit{G} \subset \Omega$ not $\Omega \subset \mathit{G}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space.

Taking ordinary expectation does not correspond to taking the conditional expectation conditioned on $\mathcal{F}$ (which is probably what you intended to write, since conditioning on $\Omega$ does not make sense). Instead, it corresponds to conditioning on the trivial sigma-field $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$, i.e.
$$
{\rm E}[X]={\rm E}[X\mid\{\varnothing,\Omega\}]
$$
for any integrable variable $X$.

In particular ${\rm E}[{\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]]={\rm E}[X]$ does not contradict the statement that
$$
{\rm E}[{\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]\mid\mathcal{H}]={\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{H}]
$$
whenever $\mathcal{H}\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ since the trivial sigma-field $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ is a subset of every sigma-field.

Comment: So does this mean that we can't refer to them as events? As how does this relate to the statement that if G is a good estimate of X then the same statement holds?

Comment: @JohnRaddison: I'm sorry, but those questions doesn't make any sense to me. What can't we refer to as events? What is $G$ and how does it estimate $X$?

Comment: I mean G and H. Surely we could refer to G & H as a certain set of events, whereby H is contained within G i.e. if we had some events ordered in time, then H occurs before G? But then I guess that to say that $\mathit{H} = \Omega$ doesn't make any sense. Not sure. Thinking aloud here and trying to clarify my thoughts.

Comment: @JohnRaddison: Yes, $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are sub-sigma-fields of $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. they're sets containing subsets of $\Omega$ (or events if you want). I usually think about them as containing information and ${\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]$ as the our best estimate of $X$ based on the information contained in $\mathcal{G}$. This is in agreement with ${\rm E}[X\mid \{\varnothing,\Omega\}]={\rm E}[X]$ meaning that with no information our best estimate is simply the mean. It is also in agreement with ${\rm E}[{\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{G}]\mid\mathcal{H}]={\rm E}[X\mid\mathcal{H}]$, right?

Comment: ...and yes $H=\Omega$ is not a set of events. Indeed $H=\{\Omega\}$ is a set of events, but this is a not a sigma-field and so conditioning on it does not make sense. The smallest sigma-field is the trivial sigma-field $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Here $H$ and $G$ are sigma-algebras, not events.

For example $E(E(X\mid G))=E(X)$ for every sigma-algebra $G$ is the case $H=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ of the preceding identity [$E(E(X\mid G)\mid H)=E(X\mid H)$ if $H\subseteq G$], since for this sigma-algebra $H$, $H\subseteq G$ is always true and $E(Y\mid H)=E(Y)$ for every (integrable) random variable.